# DAX Measure: group by min & if condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have several dataset tables in PowerBI report. The column country comes from TABLE1 while the column name comes from TABLE2.

[image]

So firstly I want to calculate min_number based on country and name, and then if min_number = number, the min will be 1; otherwise, 0. So the result table looks like:

[image]

This is my code for min

```
min = 
VAR min_number =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( [number] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( TABLE1, TABLE1[country] ), ALLEXCEPT (TABLE2, TABLE2[name])
    )
RETURN
    IF ( [number] = Min_number,1, 0 )
```

I got an error: the MIN function only accepts a column reference as the argument number 1. Does it mean if it has to be one condition? how to fix it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it by just making two separate measures, since we want to see the both results in the final table anyway.

First the min_number calculation:

```
min_number = CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[number]);ALLEXCEPT('Table';'Table'[country];'Table'[name]))
```

And the min measure:

```
min = IF(MAX('Table'[number]) = [min_number];1;0)
```

As we are using a measure, we can use MAX, so it will know what number to reference in the IF. It will still use the MAX number per row, so results are correct.

Comment: The issue is that MIN can only accept a column reference as the argument number 1. So I start experimenting MINX. Do you have any idea about how to use MINX in this expression? I got a "Heavy" result which is not displayed visually in the report, so I am not sure if the result is correct.

Comment: Yes, but you do have the [number] column? I replicated your data in Power BI and used my measure and got the expected results. I'm not sure what the issues is, is your [number] a measure of some kind?

Comment: number, country, and name are from different tables. Are you using the calculated column or measure? For measure, MIN can only evaluate one column reference. So my new code: min_number=MINX(ALLEXCEPT(TABLE1, TABLE1[Country], TABLE2[name]),[number]). The issue is that I am not able to display the new column because of exceeding available resource.

Comment: Can you post more from your model, tables and connections? I'm not really getting it. MINX is not the answer here, MIN should give you what you want, since you do have one column refence and that is the [number] -column

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this below measure-

```
min = 

VAR current_row_country = MIN(table1[country])
VAR current_row_name = MIN(table1[name])
VAR current_row_number = MIN(table1[number])

VAR min_number =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN (table1[number]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(table1),
            table1[country] = current_row_country
                && table1[name] = current_row_name
        )
    )

RETURN IF (min_number = current_row_number,1, 0 )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My categorical data comes from two tables. In the filter part, how do I add the second filter? Also, MIN does not work for me so I need to use MINX.

Comment: if tables are joined properly, they should normally. Can you add sample data from both table correctly? Otherwise its difficult to understand the real scenario.

Comment: I loaded my data table from ASS model. It is in the online model which means that I cannot open the power query or created a calculated column. All what I can do is to create measures for calculations of my interest.